# CompletableFuture not completed

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, asynchttpclient, completablefuture

Request прекрасно работает - уходит на сервер, сервер его принимает.
Затем должен прийти ответ от сервера. Но у меня не получается это сделать. Поскольку все это должно быть асинхронно, пытаюсь использовать CompletableFuture. Что бы я ни делал, и как бы ни изменял код future, оно постоянно возвращает, что future not completed, и все падает с ошибкой.

Помогите сделать так, чтобы работало, пожалуйста!

```
var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(new URI(apiUrl))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(request))
        .build();

HttpResponse.BodyHandler<String> bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString();

CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> future = client.sendAsync(httpRequest, bodyHandler);
future.thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println)
        .join();
```

Comment: Ну а что за ошибка? Может запрос не верный?

Comment: Ошибки всегда разные - то NPE, то достигнут EOF, то еще какие-то редкие исключения... Все зависит от того, что я пытаюсь в коде воспроизвести в том или ином случае. Запрос (var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()...) точно верный - до сервера он доходит, сервер его принимает и выполняет необходимую команду, фактически, этот запрос просто переписан из аналогичного синхронного алгоритма, основанного на httpURLConnection. Проблемы начинаются, когда надо принять ответ от сервера. По идее, принцип асинхронного выполнения такой, что необходимо при отправке запроса в отдельном потоке запустить

Comment: callback,который будет ждать ответа от сервера, а программа будет продолжать свое выполнение.Когда же ответ от сервера придет,callback его поймает и выполнит свою часть кода.Вот с этим я разобраться вообще не могу.Из описания HttpClient (JDK11) следует, что он этот callback создает автоматически при отправке асинхронного запроса (CompletableFuture). Но я пытался и автоматически, и явно задавать, не получается. Почему-то ответ от сервера программа не ловит (хотя при синхронном выполнении через httpURLConnection все хорошо работает), и выдает мне,что future not completed,а response body == null.

Comment: ComletableFuture возвращает void (это значение по умолчанию), хотя я ожидаю какие-то значения, и что бы я ни делал, оно все равно возвращает void

Comment: В какой именно момент вам программа выдаёт что future not completed? Если это исключение, то где трассировка стека?